# Django: how do i get values from <div> of HTML into django views and use the value?

Tags: django

so I have used leaflet and Javascript for rendering maps and calculate distance. 
the calculated distance is passed to `<div id ="distance"></div>`  and I need to extract the value and use it in django views to sort the object by distance in another page.
How do I do it?

Comment: edit: so I have used leaflet and Javascript for rendering maps and calculate distance. The calculated distance is passed to 'code' <div id="distance"></div> 'code' and I need to extract the value and use it in django views to sort the object by distance in another page. How do I do it?

Comment: You need to edit your question with the code.

Comment: @Ahtisham thank you .

Comment: extract your `distance = $("#distance").text()` and then send the data to django view with ajax `$.post('view_name', {'distance':distance},function(){});` and in django view `distance = Distance.objects.get(distance=distance)`.